# Check ALTER permission for SCHEMA

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Perhaps I have a bit silly question - do not ask why I need it, but still..
I'm working with SQL Server 2008 R2.

I granted for a user ALTER permission on 'dbo' SCHEMA:

```
USE MyDatabase
GO
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [Some\User];
GO
```

Now I'm connected to the database with that user and trying to check this permission:

```
USE MyDatabase
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('dbo', 'SCHEMA', 'ALTER');
GO
```

And it's ok, it says "1" - which means permission is set.
Now the question:
Is it possible to specify the database name somehow in the HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME's parameters itself and get rid of the statement "USE MyDatabase" preceding the permission check? To have something like this:

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('MyDatabase.dbo', 'SCHEMA', 'ALTER');
```

(which does not work actually)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of saying your problem is to find if [Some\User] can create procedures or tables in schema dbo, which can be written as:

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('MyDatabase', 'DATABASE', 'CREATE PROCEDURE')
& HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('dbo', 'SCHEMA', 'ALTER') AS _can_create_procs,
HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('MyDatabase', 'DATABASE', 'CREATE TABLE') &
HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('dbo', 'SCHEMA', 'ALTER') AS _can_create_tables;
```

For more information please read here..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Well this is a good piece of script but has nothing to do with my question :) Regarding the link to the article - I saw it. But there is no example which could give me understanding whether it's possible to achieve my goal or not at all. I tried a few variants, including this expression: SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('MyDatabase', 'DATABASE', 'ALTER', 'dbo', 'SCHEMA'); But nothing works. Maybe it's just not supposed to be used like this and I always have to call "USE" statement before HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME